# Can I combine 10 variables into one variable before performing logistic regression on 18 total variables?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, regression-strategies

[image: Univariate analysis of 18 variables associated with spine infection]

Univariate analysis of 18 variables possibly associated with spine infection--can all the historical variables be combined into one variable, then logistic regression be performed?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Data reduction is clearly a sensible approach to model fitting here - you've only 43 cases! I think you need to add a little more context about what you're trying to achieve & clarify what you're asking - how to combine them? how to decide whether to? what are alternatives? & so on.

Comment: Thank you for responding--spine infections are very low prevalence causes of a very common chief complaint presenting to Emergency Rooms, the reason they are often not diagnosed and why we only have 43. I am seeking the important predictor variables of 18 we measured that might be used in a risk stratification tool to decide who should go for expensive/time consuming  imaging (MRI).  Of the 18 variables, can I combine all ten Historical Variables into one variable (ie presence of any), then perform logistic regression on these 9 in order to find the independent predictors of spine infection?

Comment: Clarification: presence of any historic risk factor=1, presence of none=0. Now perform logistic regression on this new combined variable, along with the other 8 categorical (9 total) variables to identify the independent predictors of infection.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to explain: edit the question to add extra info. rather than appending it in comments. [The short answer is that you can combine them in the manner you've described, though obviously there are other ways you could combine them, & the most sensible method depends on their distribution in your sample & on their clinical import. Steyerberg (2009), *Clinical Prediction Models*, Ch.10, & Harrell (2001) *Regression Modelling Strategies*, Ch.4.7, deal with this issue in some depth. Note that further data reduction will likely be required to avoid over-fitting.]